# Why VSCode IntelliSense is not working with .astro files?

Tags: typescript, astrojs

I have a Astro project with Qwik and TypeScript, but my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> is not working as expected.

Screenshots:
[IntelliSense not working with Benefit component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJJPL.png)

```js
/* benefit.astro */

type Props = {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    horizontalInvertion?: boolean;
}

const { title, content, horizontalInvertion } = Astro.props;
```

[It only suggests when I start typing something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0P2q.png)

I've already tried:

- Restart VSCode
- Uninstall and install Astro extension

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected the Language Mode for `astro` files?

Via (Ctrl + K) + M or the [Select Language Mode button](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_change-the-language-for-the-selected-file) (status bar, on the right)?

[image: VS Code, Language Mode Menu, with astro selected]

Comment: Yeah, but it still doesn't work 

Comment: Too bad. :/ Can you please add the file that is seen in the screenshot to your question? So, I can test it with my setup…

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. IntelliSense for .astro components will sometimes work when I'm in the fences, but not always. Outside of the fences it sometimes displays the components as a string with the little abc in front.

Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here, but I had some similar issues with my setup today (Astro v4.4.6). I got a lot of annoying syntax errors, and many imported functions were marked as *module not found*.

Turned out I had to go into the "Extensions" tab in VS Code and do a reload of the Astro extension (which will also reload VS Code itself). Worked like a charm after that.

Could potentially be a solution to your problem (if it's still relevant).